# TinyMCE v3.4.5 Still removing <a href="#"> Even When Forcing <a> in extended_valid_elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I've already added `a[name|href|target|title|onclick|id]` to `extended_valid_elements` in my tinymce.init but `<a href="#"></a>` still get filtered out.

Should I edit the core .js or am I missing anything in my init settings?

Edit:
Here's the default config for TinyMCE on Orchard:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    theme: "advanced",
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector: "tinymce",
    plugins: "fullscreen,searchreplace,mediapicker",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "search,replace,|,cut,copy,paste,|,undo,redo,|,mediapicker,|,link,unlink,charmap,emoticon,codeblock,|,bold,italic,|,numlist,bullist,formatselect,|,code,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
    convert_urls: false,
    valid_elements: "*[*]",
    // shouldn't be needed due to the valid_elements setting, but TinyMCE would strip script.src without it.
    extended_valid_elements: "script[type|defer|src|language]"
});
```

Comment: no, never edit the core js files!!! Please post your full configuration. It might be that you have configured it to delete empty elements onCleanup.

Comment: I've updated my question. Added the default init.js of TinyMCE for Orchard...

Comment: you could use the tinymce setting cleanup: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:cleanup

Answer (score 2):

Encountered similar problem, I'm posting my answer in case anyone else will encounter it-

In TinyMCE 4.0.9 or later there is a key called:

> allow_script_urls: true;

You can set it to true and you are good to go.